# Where are the Python packages installed

Tags: python, visual-studio-2015, ptvs

I'm learning Python 3.5 using Visual Studio as my IDE. I installed the Python Tools for VS and looking at the code. I see there are a lot of from statements that reference Python packages:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth import (
    authenticate, get_user_model, password_validation,
)
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import (
    UNUSABLE_PASSWORD_PREFIX, identify_hasher,
)
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.tokens import default_token_generator
from django.contrib.sites.shortcuts import get_current_site
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives
```

Where are these pacakges stored on my Windows machine?
I tried looking in the Python installation folders/subfolders but nothing. What are the file names including the extension?

Comment: Wherever you installed Python to, probably.

Comment: If you are using virtualenv they are stored under the specific environment you are working in.  In my case .virtuenenvs is a directory in my home directory.

Comment: I found them in the env subfolder of my solution, but that is not what I'm looking for. These files may have been copied to my solution from somewhere, an original location. Similar to assemblies in ASP.NET, when you adda reference, the DLL files are located somewhere.

Comment: @Ray They were installed there using `pip`, which will have downloaded them from https://pypi.python.org/. They'll also be cached somewhere locally on your machine, but that isn't something to worry about - the official source is on the Python Package Index (PyPI).

Answer (score 2):

`__future__` isn't a package - it's a special [*future statement*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/__future__.html) which declares the use of a planned Python feature.

For your other packages, you'll usually find them in your Python install location (for me, this was `C:\Python34`) > `Lib` > `site-packages`. Here there are directories for most packages, and then `.py` files for some others.

If you can't find packages there, have a look at the value of the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable on your system. This will point to extra packages not found in `Lib/site-packages`.

Comment: I found the site-packages folder but the packages above like django.contrib.auth.models are not in there. What is the extension to these files? Secondly, I don`t have a PYTHONPATH environment variable defined. My app runs though.